# What is the best way to convert a ByteString to an Int?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I always run into the following error when trying to read a ByteString:
`Prelude.read: no parse`

Here's a sample of code that will cause this error to occur upon rendering in a browser:

```
factSplice :: SnapletSplice App App
factSplice = do
    mbstr <- getParam "input" -- returns user input as bytestring
    let str = maybe (error "splice") show mbstr
    let n = read str :: Int
    return [X.TextNode $ T.pack $ show $ product [1..n]]
```

Or perhaps more simply:

```
simple bs = read (show bs) :: Int
```

For some reason, after `show bs` the resulting string includes quotes.
So in order to get around the error I have to remove the quotes then `read` it.
I use the following function copied from the internet to do so:

```
sq :: String -> String
sq s@[c]                     = s
sq ('"':s)  | last s == '"'  = init s
            | otherwise      = s
sq ('\'':s) | last s == '\'' = init s
            | otherwise      = s
sq s                         = s
```

Then `simple bs = read (sq.show bs) :: Int` works as expected.

1. Why is this the case?
2. What is the best way to convert a ByteString to an Int?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Show` is used to create a `String` representation of something, that is useful for **debugging** and **plain-text serialization**. The `Show` typeclass is not just a fancy way of converting anything into a `String`. That's why `ByteString` adds quotes to the string: because it's arguably easier to read it that way when debugging or deserializing a data stream.

You can use the [`Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:unpack) function to convert a `ByteString` to a `String`, but note that this unpacks the `ByteString` byte-per-byte, which messes up high-value Unicode characters or other characters that are stored as more than one byte; if you want to do something other than using `read` on the result, I'd recommend converting the `ByteString` to [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html) instead, which offers more flexibility in this situation. Assuming that your encoding is UTF8 in this case (As should be the default in Snap), you can use the [`Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:decodeUtf8) function for this. To then convert a `Text` value to a `String` with correct Unicode symbols, you use [`Data.Text.unpack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v:unpack).

Once you have a `String`, you are free to `read` it as much as you want; alternatively, you can choose to read a `Text` value directly using the functions in the [`Data.Text.Read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.12/doc/html/Data-Text-Read.html) module.

Comment: To me question #2 is still not that clear--or it may be just a more specific use case I'm curious about and I think is related to this initial question:
What if there is some sort of a "lenght field" that is parsed as a ByteString of lenght 4, which in fact describes an Int32. Is your proposed workaround still valid? As a more comfortable solution I was looking for a library that can take such kind of a ByteString and will return the correct Int. Is there any library that can handle this use case?

Answer (score 13):

What the best way to convert a `ByteString` to an `X` is depends on`X`. If you have a good conversion from `String`, going via `Data.BytString.Char8.unpack` can be good, if it's an ASCII `ByteString`. For UTF-8 encoded `ByteString`s, the [utf8-string](http://hackage/haskell.org/package/utf8-string) package contains the conversion function `toString`. For some specific types, like `Int`, as mentioned in the title, special faster conversions exist. For example `Data.ByteString.Char8.readInt` and `readInteger`.

Comment: For those who are coming in from the internet: **This is the answer if "best way" also means "efficient way" for you!**